# Как сделать запрос на выборку по связанным данным по строгому параметру

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос

Суть в чём, допустим есть таблица `color` в которой набор полей `id, product_id, quantity` и таблица `product` с полями `id, sku`, нужно выбрать все товары в которых `quantity > 0` на каждый цвет. Как в таком случае поступить, ничего в голову не может придти?

Даю больше информации:

**color**

```
|id|product_id|quantity|
|1 |1         |0       |
|2 |1         |1       |
|3 |2         |1       |
|4 |3         |1       |
|5 |3         |1       |
```

нужно чтоб в итоге показало только `product_id=2,3` так как они имеют коли чисто, в `product_id=1` есть поле з `quantity=0`

Comment: Почему ID повторяются?

Comment: Поправлю, незаметил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`distinct` выборку сделайте и все

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.sku 
FROM product AS p 
INNER JOIN color AS c ON c.product_id = p.id and c.quantity > 0
```

или подзапросом

```
SELECT p.id, p.sku
FROM products as p 
WHERE id IN (select distinct product_id from color where quantity > 0)
```

или смешайте оба подхода - приджойньте подзапрос (возможно это будет наиболее быстрый вариант, кстати)

```
SELECT p.id, p.sku
FROM products as p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT distinct product_id FROM color WHERE quantity > 0
) AS x ON x.product_id = p.id
```

можно применить группировку, но это избыточный инструмент для данной задачи/

апд. чтобы оставить в выборке только те, у которых нет нулевых цветов, то очевидные пути будут

```
seleсе distict product_id 
from color 
where quantity > 0 
    and product_id not in (
             select distinct product_id 
             from color 
             where qunatity = 0 )
```

либо с группировкой с подсчетом нулевых строк

```
select product_id
from colors
group by product_id
having sum(if(quantity = 0, 1, 0)) = 0
```

либо самоджойн ненулевых с нулевыми.

```
select distinct c.product_id 
from colors  as c
left join colors as c2 on (c2.product_id = c.product_id and c2.quantity = 0)  
where c.quantity > 0 
     and c2.product_id is null
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, при таком подходе в выборку попадут и товары в которых есть цвета с нулевым количеством, то есть как в вопросе выше, так как в продукт есть две связи на цвет и в одной ис связей есть количество то под любой из вариантов она подходит, то есть смысл в том чтобы если на продукт есть хотя бы одна запись с цветом количеством 0 то данный продукт уже не должен попадать в выборку. Можно сделать через запрос в обратку под запросом вытянуть все продукты в которых есть цвет с количеством 0 и в основном через NOT IN уже выбрать нужные, но возможно есть какой-то больше совершенный способ

Comment: @UKRman вот так и надо разъяснять в изначальном вопросе

Comment: @UKRman дополнил варианты

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо использовать группировку и групповые функции

```
select
  group_concat(p.sku separator ', ') skus, c.id
from product p,
     color c
where c.product_id = p.id
and   c.quantity > 0
group by c.id
```

Если в таблице все таки есть поле `color` нужно группировать по нему. Поле `skus` содержит перечень продуктов через запятую

Comment: Тоисть таким способом в skus будут только ид продуктов в которых есть все цвета имеют хотя бы 1 quantity?

Comment: Просто вы написали на каждый цвет, поэтому я сделал группировку. В `SKUS` перечисление всех `sku` товаров с определеным цветом и количество больше 0.

Comment: Нє, мне нужно найти только те товары в которых в каждого цвета есть значения больше 1, ну проверка должна быть на каждый цвет, в вопрос показал пример что нужно получиться в итоге, спасибо за ваш ответ.